# trying to install php fails because of python dependency?

Tags: php

I just wanted to install php on Mac

```
brew install PHP
...
==> Installing php dependency: python@3.8
==> Pouring python@3.8-3.8.6.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
brew link --overwrite python@3.8

To list all files that would be deleted:
brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@3.8
```

I don't pretend to understand why PHP has a dependency on python...I'd like just to use it.
I don't feel safe either rm te conflicting files as I need python...